Sumar registros por código en la misma tabla desde otra columna
Filtré valores del último registro de cada código de una columna de una tabla, sin embargo, también quiero sumar valores de varios registros con el mismo código de otra columna de la misma tabla y no salen los resultados esperados o no suman
Aquí le dejo el script del filtro de últimos valores:
SELECT a.codigo, a.fecha, a.precio_venta, SUM(pack) stock
FROM mercaderia as a
INNER JOIN ( SELECT codigo, MAX(fecha) fecha_max
            FROM mercaderia
            where pack>0
            GROUP BY codigo) b
            ON a.codigo = b.codigo
            AND a.fecha = b.fecha_max
GROUP BY codigo
HAVING SUM(pack)

Intenté hacer la suma de la columna pack con HAVING agrupado por la columna código y al parecer arroja resultados sin dicha suma o no está sumando.

Ese titulo XDDD Yussef, cambialo al menos xDDD

A Daniel, que otra columna es la que quieres consultar ?? detalla mejor eso por favor.

hola Excorpion, Solo tengo un tabla que la nombré "mercaderia" en ella tengo columnas de las cuales quiero hacer 2 consultas simultaneamente, una de ellas ya la hice que es la del filtro que muestra el ultimo registro de la columna "precio_venta" por cada codigo. La otra consulta es: quiero sumar la columna "pack" agrupado por codigo es decir un codigo tiene varios registros con diferentes valores en la col. "pack" y quiero sumar todos para que me arroje un total por cada codigo. ya lo hice con HAVING y no esta sumando (ojo las 2 consultas tiene que visualizarse simultaneamente en una tabla x)

Amm, cual de los 2 comentarios es el real ? XD

Hasta donde entiendo, la idea es:

Obtener el último precio_venta de cada codigo.
Obtener la suma total de pack por cada codigo.
Combinar ambas subconsultas en una sola consulta principal.

Si es asi, habría que hacer una subconsulta.
Nueva edición:
SELECT 
    m.codigo,
    MAX(m.fecha) AS fecha,  -- ultima fecha por codigo
    (SELECT ms.precio_venta
     FROM mercaderia ms
     WHERE ms.codigo = m.codigo
     ORDER BY ms.fecha DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS ultimo_precio_venta, -- subconsulta para el ultimo precio_venta por codigo
    SUM(m.pack) AS total_pack -- suma de pack por codigo
FROM mercaderia m
GROUP BY m.codigo
ORDER BY m.codigo

Espero esto si satisfaga las necesidades, por que cumple las condiciones acordadas.

hola otra vez Escorpion . pack son solo numeros enteros para que me entiendas mejor la tabla mercaderia es como un kardex (tabla donde se registra ingreso y salida de mercaderia ) y el pack son las cantidades osea numero mayo a cero si ingresa y numero menor a cero si sale mercaderia (venta) y la consulta que quiero hacer es para sumar y mostra como resultado el stock (existencias actuales con las que se cuenta) ....  Intente con el script que enviaste y tanpoco, no esta sumando :( la idea es que cada consulta es independiente, los resultados tienen que ser de la tabla de origen "mercaderia"

osea tabla de origen no corrompida, no alterada por ninguna otra consulta es decir no tiene que estar alterada por la consulta de filtro que hice. basicamente la tabla resultado tiene que ser asi:                                                                               codigo   |   fecha_max   |   total_pack(stock)                                                            c0001     |   2024-10-01 |   10                                                                                  c0002     |   2024-09-15 |    6

bueno yo tb estoy con una tabla de prueba es decir aun no tengo la tabla real porque recien lo estoy implemtando pero tratare de subir una imagen de XAMPP

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bO-0UnasspGnD6JxoIuhtfY7fP8n7waE/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                          tal como te comente la tabla no es real aun, necesito el script para recien implementarla por ende los datos no son reales, en el enlace que te evnio esta una imagen de la tabla mercaderia

hola excorpion creo que esta pagina web ya es obsoleta, XD me podrias recomendar un grupo o red social donde hagan este tipo de preguntas por favor necesito terminar este script esta semana por favoorrrrrrrrrrrrr!

ya ingrese, pero que se supone que debo hacer ahi ? me sale que debo tener 20 puntos de reputacion para poder hablar

la base seria en excel ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDQnkEaqtXmMwnyO4jem9D0cX6JVv5Mb/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                 llisto, se agradece de antemano

Subi una nueva edición, y cumplí todas las condiciones con revisión manual incluso. Me enfoque bastante en el código 4, ya que ese se repite más. 1.- Ultima fecha 2.- ultimo precio venta 3.- suma total de pack por codigo

brother graciasssssssssssssssssssssssss :)

De nada :3 por favor recuerda darme +1 y además! marcar la respuesta como correcta, con el tick en verde. Gracias :D

listo ya le di el tick verde ahora solo falta darle +1 que no encuentro donde es...

Debería ser una flecha grande apuntando para arriba, a menos que sea de esos privilegios de la página.... y revisando, si... necesitas 15 puntos para votar positivo jaja Sigue usando el sitio, ayudando, comentando, preugntando, etc, y adquiriras esos puntos.

ah ok entiendo, bueno continuare con mi proyecto si tengo otra consutla te paso la voz ;-)

Hola Excorpion, 2 consultas,                                                                              La primera Existira algun script para lograr que una jframe se abra solo una vez desde un boton desde otra jframe?                                                                  La segunda, Existira un script para actualizacion automatica de datos de tabla java registrados en base datos sql,? es decir se registra en base datos y se visualice automaticamente en la tabla de una jfrma sin que lo cierre y lo vuelva a abrir otra vez

1.- Si, con algun tipo de variable booleana podrías controlar el estado y cambiarlo cuando quieras. 2.- Depende de que estes usando, pero si. En java, con un thread por ejemplo.

sobre la consulta 1 ya probe con variables booleana sin embargo solo me permite abrir una vez es decir si cierro el jframe y quiero volver abrirlo ya no se puede.

No vas controlando/cambiando la variable en cada momento?

mas o menos hice asi:
boolean opc = true;(Variable general)
if(opc == true){
VentanaDos vent = new VentanaDos();
vent.setVisible(true);
opc = false
}else{
....Pane.show....(null, Ventana ya esta abierta)
}
Como seria para controlar la variable???

Bueno, te invito a crear una nueva pregunta, en donde muestres como intentaste controlar la variable, por que la verdad debería funcionar.

ok me respondes porfas

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/628071/como-evitar-abrir-mas-de-un-jframe-desde-otro
listo ese es el link
