COMO EVITAR ABRIR MAS DE UN JFRAME DESDE OTRO
Estoy intentando crear un script en la cual solo permita abrir 1 solo jframe y que cuando lo cierre y lo vuelva abrir visualice el mismo jframe.
investigue en google y halle que se puede hacer con singleton la cual te permite hacer hacer instancia o eso etendi ahi el script:
public static IngresoMercaderia getInstancia(){
    if(instancia == null) {
        instancia = new IngresoMercaderia(); 
        getInstancia().setVisible(true);
    } return instancia;
}

para ello cree una variable global:
private static IngresoMercaderia instancia;

y desde el jframe principal en menuItem formule lo siguiente:
IngresoMercaderia.getInstancia();

sin embargo no obtube el resultado esperado, todo bien hasta que cierro el jframe y ya no me deja abrirlo otra vez.
Porfavor espero con muchas ansias sus respuestas... gracias

Cuando cierras el JFrame, este se destruye, ya no existe. En vez de destruirlo, podrías probar a ocultarlo. Cambiando el close por el comportamiento HIDE -> setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE) . No se como tengas el constructor de todo esto, pero asi se oculta, y luego para mostrarlo getInstancia().setVisible(true);. Entonces mientras está oculto, lo puedes editar, cambiar, etc. Y como te dije antes, este estado lo puedes controlar con un boolean como bandera para saber si esta mostrandose o no.

mientras esta oculto no deseo hacer nada ni quiero que este apto para modificar solo quiero que me deje abrirlo otra vez para poder emplearlo......
getInstancia().setVisible(true);  este codigo le tipeo en menuITem?

Hola Daniel, el metodo getInstancia() es medio... feito, si instancia es null,crea una nueva instancia (bien) y luego hace recursión para usar setVisible, es un poco rebuscado, es mas facil usarlo directamente, no?, otra forma de lograr lo que quieres es quitarle el marco al frame, y usar un boton para cerrarlo, usando: instancia.setVisible( false );.

como no hay nada de sql modfiqué las etiquetas de tu pregunta

Debes crear una variable global e inicializar
private static IngresoMercaderia instancia;

Luego instanciarlo
public static instanciar(){
instancia = new IngresoMercaderia();
instancia.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

Luego debes llamar a la instancia y hacerlo visible.
public static setVisible(boolean b){
instancia.setVisible(b);
}


Hola Nicolas soy nuevo en programacion y solo se puntos basicos, me podrias explicar mejor en que jframe debo poner esos codigos en jframe principal o en el jframe que quiero abrir (IngresoMercaderia) ?
